# Problem with HostGator addon domain

Tags: wordpress, hostgator, add-on-domain

I installed WordPress on an addon domain in my HostGator account. When I go to the wp-admin url and sign in I see this. Does anyone know what's up with this?
Thanks[image]

Comment: What is the full url you are using? (User example.com instead of your real domain).

Comment: I do not use WP. By add on domain, do you mean a new domain name or a sub-domain? If a new domain, when was it registered? Did you create an A record? Did you properly add your domain via cPanel? When I see this, it tells me that the web server does not recognize the domain name in the request header.

Comment: That looks to me like either you have the URL wrong, the nameservers are wrong, or you haven't verified the domain and after 15 days it has been suspended and is showing ads instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you added on a domain name, make sure the domain is officially registered, and DNS is set properly and propagation is completed (usually about 24 to 48 hours). You can call HostGator.com via live chat http://chat.hostgator.com/ or via telephone 866-964-2867 available 24 hours a day to get assistance.

https://www.hostgator.com/help > you can search 'addon domain' for steps and help, also if you are calling internationally if you search 'skype' from our support pages, we have the steps on how to call us locally/internationally.